# Visual Studio wpf project C# contextmenu icon next to mrenuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, contextmenu

I've got big problem despite all my efforts I cannot add an icon next to menu item in notifyicon contextmenu. I want to create contextmenu with icons which render using windows theme so its changing looks accordingly to windows version. I've tried using custom render ownerdraw but it look more like contextmenustrip now and render same on all windows versions which is not my desired effect. I wonder it is even possible to get icons in tray contextmenu using visual studio and c# code and keep windows look and feel.

If anyone knows solution to this I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Community or similar, if not, let me know if this is significantly more different!

Check out [Guide to Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894631.aspx)

If you are using UWP, then the Universal Windows Programming using XAML, you might consider using:

Adaptive scaling, 
In this case you would use the XAML Tag .
In the case of the relative panel you will see that objects will move around and adapt in a Windows 10 media way, to the screen size.  You could modify the adaptive action using XAML.  [Jerry Nixon](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/) has a great blog on XAML and C#, read it.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'm using visual studio 2013 on win 7 and visual studio 2015 on win 10. I have created an app using wpf and implementing forms controls with notifyicon and contextmenu rendering by windows. It look great on win 7, 8 and win 10 but I'm still not able to put icons next to menuitems. Point is if I use ownerdraw property menu look like contextmenustrip and its loosing slick windows render look.